# How to update the WHOLE state in React-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I understand how to update some attributes in the state in redux but, is this good practice if I want to update the WHOLE state? I could obviously copy the current state and modify each attribute of that copy but for objects with a lot of attributes this would be quite time consuming.

```
const gameReducer = (state:IGame, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GAME_STARTED":
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return initialState;
  }
};
export default gameReducer;
```

Comment: That's how it works though, which means you need to structure your state in a way that avoids doing that. For instance by using [slices](https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start#create-a-redux-state-slice)

Comment: I don't understand why though, I'm not saying state: action.payload and then returning the state, i'm returning a new object instead?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. A reducer is a function that takes the previous state and an action, and returns the new state. So if you return `action.payload` it means that your state is now `action.payload`. There is no requirement to actually use the previous state, even though in most cases you do want to use it.

Comment: Ok thank you that's exactly what I wanted to hear. I thought that I had to create a new object from the current state and then modify that one, and return it. But if you say I can just return whatever(without modifying the previous state of course), then that solves my misunderstanding.